# adding fixed size JPanels to a jScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

in my project i have a scrollpane which can contains various panel, depending by user action.
By the way, i'd like to have each panel of a fixed height, and on add, they should be shown one below the previous. Instead they change their height depending to the number of existing panels.
I wrote a main class with the goal of reproducing current behaviour, and an image which should explain what am I aiming for.

image:

[image]

code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MyClass {

    static JScrollPane myScrollPaneContent;
    static Box panelContainer;
    static int i=0;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {       
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){   
                int i=0;
                //mainWindow
                    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("MyFrame");
                    mainWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    mainWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1050,300));

                //panel to be placed in mainwindow (borderlayout.Center)
                //contains a menu + scrollpane
                    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();

                //Box for myScrollPaneContent
                panelContainer = Box.createVerticalBox(); 

                    //button for centerPanel
                    JButton button = new JButton("addPanel");
                    button.setBackground(Color.green);
                    button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                            //nothing
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                            //nothing
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                            //nothing
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                            //nothing
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            addPanel();
                        }

                    });
                    centerPanel.add(button);


                    myScrollPaneContent = new JScrollPane(panelContainer);
                    myScrollPaneContent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,250));
                    myScrollPaneContent.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

                    //all panels are added to the Box


                    //the box do not need to be added to scroll pane since it has been given into it s constructor

                    //the scrollpane is added to the centralpanel
                    centerPanel.add(myScrollPaneContent);

                    mainWindow.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    mainWindow.add(Box.createVerticalGlue(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);


                    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }




    public static void addPanel(){
        switch(i++){
        case 0:
            //panel 1 for Box
            JPanel one = new JPanel();
            JLabel labOne = new JLabel("hello");
            one.add(labOne);
            one.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,25));
            one.setBackground(Color.white);
            panelContainer.add(one);

            break;
        case 1:
            //panel 2 for Box
            JPanel two = new JPanel();
            JLabel labTwo = new JLabel("i am a label");
            two.add(labTwo);
            two.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,30));
            two.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            panelContainer.add(two);
            break;
        case 2:
            //panel 3 for Box
            JPanel three = new JPanel();
            JLabel labThree = new JLabel("Bye bye");
            three.add(labThree);
            three.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,30));
            three.setBackground(Color.gray);
            panelContainer.add(three);
            break;
        case 3:
            //panel 4 for Box
            JPanel four = new JPanel();
            JLabel labFour = new JLabel("boyz");
            four.add(labFour);
            four.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,30));
            four.setBackground(Color.blue);
            panelContainer.add(four);
            break;
        default: 
            i=0;
            break;
        }
        myScrollPaneContent.revalidate();
        myScrollPaneContent.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"in my project i have a scrollpane which can contains various panel, depending by user action."*  Sounds better suited to a `JList` with an appropriate cell renderer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
JPanel scrollPaneContainer = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
Box panelContainer = Box.createVerticalBox(); 
scrollPaneContainer.add(panelContainer, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
JScrollPane myScrollPaneContent = new JScrollPane(scrollPaneContainer);
```

Now the preferred height of your panelContainer will be respected. If there is any extra spaces it will go to the CENTER. If there is not enough space, the scrollbars will appear.

Also, you should NOT be using static variables. This is the sign of a poorly designed GUI. You should NOT be creating your GUI components in main() method. Look at the demos from the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). They show you how to create a panel to hold the Swing components and then add the panel to the frame.

Comment: it works properly.
By the way, i notice i can't add a JPanel to a certain index since the Box class do not has the getIndexOf() method. Do you have any suggestion?